# How to automate a function which will have variable input in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I am trying to make a function that will produce single line of code, but for each instance of use the line may differ based on the input data.

The line I am trying to replicate is this

```
model1 <- lm(DF[,2]~DF[,3]+DF[,4]+DF[,5]+DF[,6]+DF[,7])
```

I have attempted to automate this from `DF` using a simple `For loop`
Here `DF[,2]~DF[,3] will be the only constant variables. Following columns can exist, or not exist.

```
minimumCode <- "DF[,2]~DF[,3]"
additionCode <- "+DF[,"
closeCode <- "]"

for (i in seq_along(4:length(colnames(DF)))) {
    print(i+3)
    code <- paste0(minimumCode, additionCode, i, closeCode)
    
}
code

"DF[,2]~DF[,3]+DF[,4]"
```

The example DF is below. However other inputs could have many more or fewer columns.

```
DF <- structure(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 14, 1220.574, 860.019, 839.642, 564.16, 
413.3933333333, 576.577, 27.3333333333, 100, 243, 193.6666666667, 
139.6666666667, 57.6666666667, 99.3333333333, 72.6666666667, 
94.6666666667, 77.6666666667, 139, 120.3333333333, 245.3333333333, 
238, 545.6666666667, 463, 517.3333333333, 298.3333333333, 4, 
7.3333333333, 22.6666666667, 25.3333333333, 19.6666666667, 17, 
0, 1, 3, 2.6666666667, 5.6666666667, 0.3333333333), .Dim = 6:7, .Dimnames = list(
    c("D0", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5"), c("Time", "Y", "X1", 
    "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5")))
```

Comment: Rather than paste together a *string*, you can directly construct the *formula expression* using metaprogramming.

Comment: 1) `length(colnames(DF))` is equal to the simpler `ncol(DF)`. 2) You want just the formulas or the linear models?

Comment: I would ideally like to use the ```lm``` function on the output of the pasted object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following function is what is asked for.

```
linearRegr <- function(data, resp = 2, regr.fixed = 3, regr.other){
  vars <- names(data)
  fmla <- paste(vars[resp], vars[regr.fixed], sep = "~")
  if(!missing(regr.other)){
    other <- paste(vars[regr.other], collapse = "+")
    fmla <- paste(fmla, other, sep = "+")
  }
  fmla <- as.formula(fmla)
  list(formula = fmla, regression = lm(fmla, data = data))
}

linearRegr(DF, regr.other = 4:7)
#$formula
#Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5
#<environment: 0x5568142139e8>
#
#$regression
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = fmla, data = data)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           X1           X2           X3           X4           X5  
#    880.262       -2.304       -6.124        4.948      -50.552     -151.624  
#
```

---

```
model1 <- linearRegr(DF, regr.other = 4:5)
summary(model1$regression)
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = fmla, data = data)
#
#Residuals:
#     D0      D1      D2      D3      D4      D5 
# 253.52  -67.95  278.73 -252.54  -82.27 -129.49 
#
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept) 1731.946    914.966   1.893    0.199
#X1            -4.110      9.941  -0.413    0.719
#X2           -10.129     16.968  -0.597    0.611
#X3             1.441      5.910   0.244    0.830
#
#Residual standard error: 342 on 2 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.4423,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.3943 
#F-statistic: 0.5287 on 3 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.7058
```